# Sort an arraylist by array element

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

so I'm adding arrays to my arraylist and I want it to be sorted by the second element of the arrays, is that possible, here is the code that I wrote but doesn't return the correct output,

```
[5.0, 0.0, 2.0]
[1.0, 2.0, 0.0]
[2.0, 5.0, 0.0]
[3.0, 3.0, 0.0]
[0.0, 8.0, 2.0]

  public void add(double[] k){

    if(a.size()==0){
        a.add(k);

    }
    else if(k[1]<=a.get(0)[1]){
        a.add(0,k);

    }
    else if(k[1]>a.get(0)[1]) {
        int i =0;
        while(a.get(i)[1]<k[1] && i<a.size()-1){
            i++;
        }
        a.add(i+1,k);
    }
    length++;
}

public  void apr(){

    for(int i=0; i<a.size(); i++)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a.get(i)));
    }   

public static void main(String args[]){
    double k[]= {1,2,0};
    double k1[]= {2,5,0};
    double k2[] = {3,3,0};
    double k3[] = {5,0,2};
    double k4[] = {0,8,2};
    Sample amostra1 = new Sample();
            amostra1.add(k);
    amostra1.add(k1);
    amostra1.add(k2);
    amostra1.add(k3);
    amostra1.add(k4);
    amostra1.apr();
```

The first lines are the output which is incorrect, and I wanted the arrays to be sorted by their second component, or by their first component, its just a little modification in the code i guess

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way with a custom comparator for the ArrayList:

```
Collections.sort(amostra1, new Comparator<double[]>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(double[] o1, double[] o2) {
                int index = 1; // second element of the array
                return Double.compare(o1[index], o2[index]);
            }
        });
```

To sort according to the first element of the array just set index to 0 and you get the array sorted according to the first element.

Note that Collections.sort(...) takes a **List** and a **Comparator**

Comment: Nope, that didn't work because my Arraylist is an Arraylist of arrays, it says that the method isn't applicable for the arguments

Comment: Are you sure the parameters you used for the comparators are arrays? because in the above example they are (double[]). Honestly I tried this code before submitting and it worked for amostra1 being an ArrayList and not a Sample. :)
The error you're getting is not because of the comparator but because of "Sample" class you are using (it's not a List) this is what the method is seeing, make sure that the method sort(...) takes a **List** input as I mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a "sorting" algorithm for my add function, because my sample is an arraylist, and I can't make a list,, so here's what I ended up doing, being "a" my arraylist that is defined later as a sample. There were some problems with above algorithm because it didn't account for inserting smaller elements than the last one of the list, or inserting in the middle of the list. This sorts by the first component, but if you change a.get(i)[0] to a.get(i)[1] it sorts by the second, thanks for the help anyway ;)

```
public void add(double[] k){

          if(a.size()==0 || a.get(0)[0]>k[0]){
               a.add(0,k);
          }
          else {
              int i=0;
              while(a.get(i)[0]<k[0]&& i<a.size()-1){
                  i++;
          }
             if(i==a.size()-1 && a.get(i)[0]>k[0] ||(i!=a.size()-1 && a.get(i)[0]>k[0]) ){
                 a.add(i,k);
             }
             else if(i==a.size()-1 && a.get(i)[0]<k[0] || (i!=a.size()-1 && a.get(i)[0]<k[0])){
              a.add(i+1,k);
          }

             }
          length++;
             }
```